# Android: cancel() on Animation does not work

Tags: java, android, animation, cancellation, objectanimator

I have been working on a little game and I need a progress bar animation, which begins when I touch a button for the first time and if I touch the button again before the animation ended the progressbar needs to reset.

In my code `animation.start();` works well but the `animation.cancel()` does not seem to work.

[French Version of this Question](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/android-annuler-une-animation-impossible)

**My Activity Code containing the line that does not work:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b_bleu;
    PrgressBar bar1;

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        b_bleu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(bar1, "progress", 100, 0);
            animation.setDuration(5000);
            animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    //application se termine
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });

            animation.cancel();
            animation.start();
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not seem to work"? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `animation.cancel()` has no effect since you call `animation.start();` right after it.

Try something like this:

Declare a field:

```
private boolean mStarted = false;
```

Then set it in animation callbacks and check its value:

```
animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        mHasStarted = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        mHasStarted = false; // reset the field value so that it can be started again onClick once it has ened
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
       mHasStarted = false;
    }
});

if (mStarted) {
    animation.cancel();
} else {
    animation.start();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for you answer, but i find a solution with animation.setAutoCancel(false) :)  if someone want the code, ask me ;)